# Loop does not stop even after passing condition

Tags: c, mplab

```
  void initTimer (void);
void delay (unsigned long milli);

void main (void)
{
//initialize peripherals
 initTimer();
//PORTB all outputs
 TRISB = 0;
 
 LATB = 0;
 
 TRISA = 0x0F;
 
 ANSA = 0;
 
 

unsigned int allon = 0b1111111111111111;
unsigned int counter;
unsigned int zero =  0b0000000000000000;


  if (PORTAbits.RA0 == 1 && PORTAbits.RA1 == 1 && PORTAbits.RA2 == 0)
        
            for (counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
            {
            LATB = allon;
            delay(SHORT_DELAY); 
            LATB = zero;
            delay(LONG_DELAY);
            }
}
```

I thought this was like the most foolproof code ever, but it doesnt stop after 5 times, not sure whats going on. The variables are set to binary, which determines which outputs are on or off, zero is alloff, and allon is the opposite

Comment: " it doesnt stop after 5 times," --> What does it do?  What is the evidence that loop iterates 5 times?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't stop?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica my fault for that, it keeps going, so the inputs continue to loop, regardless of the for loop

Comment: @EugeneSh. the outputs are leds, so its visible

Comment: What is `allon` ? What is `zero`? Please post [mcve]

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica the loop iterates infinitely, as is visible on the outputs, which are leds

Comment: Perhaps the loop ends, only to code re-start and get entered again.

Comment: This might be a part of bigger loop. Or the whole thing is resetting at some point. [mcve] is needed.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica there is no while(1) loop

Comment: @EugeneSh. made updates to question, sorry for that

Comment: If there is no `while(1)` loop, then your program is eventually "terminating" which is not good for embedded bare-metal firmware. It has nowhere to return. It *must* have an infinite loop.

Comment: The update is not a [mcve] for sure. It has `else` without `if`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. i see. well all the other loops are working by themselves and are else or if else statements.

Comment: @EugeneSh. where is that?

Comment: @EugeneSh. i just noticed that there are no square brackets for if else, could that be the problem?

Comment: The problem as I said - `main` cannot terminate, it has to get stuck after execution, or execute something forever. Add `while(1);` in the end of it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. that was the solution, add while(1) to the end, you can post as an answer, if youd like, thanks

Comment: @SK-11BJ816097RickHansenS My [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67081623/loop-does-not-stop-even-after-passing-condition?noredirect=1#comment118572932_67081623) refers to the posted `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike programs in hosted environments (that is running under OS) which can "return" from main by passing control back to the host, embedded bare-metal programs have nowhere to return. So a typical bare-metal program should have an infinite loop somewhere - either as some even-processing loop, periodic task loop or just in the end of the `main` function in case it has a finite sequence of actions. In your case it seem to be the last one - you only want to blink few times and halt. So the solution is to place

```
while(1);
```

in the end of `main` function such that it will enter infinite idle loop after execution until reset.

Comment: `while(1);` OK for debugging, but better to re-start,

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica What do you mean by restart? If it is a system that is designed to blink 5 times upon power up, there is nothing to restart. Sure better to put it into some kind of low power state, but it is depending on the processor features.

Comment: Embedded system that encounter end-of-main or UB often result a re-start.  OP may be observing that given "it keeps going".